# How to prove the following formula?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ be a holomorphic function. Then how to show
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{u(\zeta)-iv(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta = u(0)-iv(0)$$ where $\gamma$ is a circle centered at $0$ and $z$ is in the interior of $\gamma$.

Comment: It seems that this follows immediately from the Cauchy integral formula

Comment: @Matt I'm not sure that it does, because $u-iv$ is not holomorphic.  But the question is clearly wrong because it would give not $(u-iv)(0)$ but $(u-iv)(z)$ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume for simplicity that $\gamma $ is the unit circle and $$f(z)=\sum_{k=0} ^\infty a_kz^k$$ is analytic on $|z|\le 1$, that is, $$\sum_{k=0} ^\infty a_kz^k$$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $\gamma $ .

First we note that
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \frac{1}{\zeta -z}\, d\zeta &=2\pi i,\\ 
\int_\gamma \frac{\overline{\zeta^n}}{\zeta -z}\, d\zeta &=0, \quad (n\ge 1)\tag{1}
\end{align}
for $z$ inside $\gamma $.
Then we have \begin{align}
\int_\gamma \frac{\overline{f(\zeta)}}{\zeta -z}\,d\zeta&=\int_\gamma \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \overline{a_k\zeta^k}\right)\frac{1}{\zeta -z}\, d\zeta \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \overline{a_k}\int _\gamma  \frac{\overline{\zeta^k }}{\zeta -z}\,d\zeta \\
&=2\pi i\,\overline{a_0}=2\pi i\,\overline{f(0)},
\end{align}
which completes the proof.

Proof of $(1)$.
Since $\overline{\zeta }=\frac{1}{\zeta}$ for $\zeta \in \gamma $, we have $$
\int_\gamma  \frac{\overline {\zeta ^n}}{\zeta -z}\, d\zeta =\int_\gamma  \frac{d\zeta }{(\zeta -z)\zeta ^n}.
$$
Notice that $\frac{1}{(\zeta -z)\zeta ^n}$ is analytic on the annulus $1\le |\zeta |\le R$. Therefore we have by Cauchy theorem that
$$
\int_\gamma  \frac{d\zeta }{(\zeta -z)\zeta ^n}=\int_{|\zeta |=R}  \frac{d\zeta }{(\zeta -z)\zeta ^n}
$$
and it is easy to see that
$$
\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{|\zeta |=R}  \frac{d\zeta }{(\zeta -z)\zeta ^n} =0,
$$
which completes the proof of $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$u$ and $v$ are harmonic, thus the Mean Value Property of harmonic functions gives

$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{u(\zeta)-iv(\zeta)}{\zeta-z_0}d\zeta = u(z_0)-iv(z_0)$

where $\gamma(t)=z_0 +re^{it}$ and $r$ so that $\{z: |z-z_0| \le r\}$ is contained in the domain of $f$

Comment: That is not the Mean Value Property of harmonic functions.  The Mean Value Property of harmonic functions is $u(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{\gamma}u(\zeta)$.

Comment: No ! The mean Value Property reads as follows: $u(z_0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{2 \pi}u(z_0+re^{it}) dt$. Your integral: $\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{\gamma}u(\zeta) d \zeta=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{2 \pi}u(z_0+re^{it})rie^{it} dt$

Comment: I guess I should have written $d\theta$ at the end to make it correct.  Anyway, neither of these are what you wrote, and neither correspond to what the OP wants.

Comment: What ?? $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{u(\zeta)}{\zeta-z_0} d \zeta=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}\frac{u(z_0 +r e^{it})}{re^{it}}rie^{it} dt=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{2 \pi}u(z_0+re^{it}) dt = u(z_0)$

Comment: Ok, you're right.  I guess I don't see things if they're not spelled out for me.